# Can I run Trezor Wallet against my own local node on OSX?

Tags: mac, full-node, trezor, bitcore

I want to point [Trezor Wallet](https://wallet.trezor.io) at my own local node. I'm already running Bitcoin Core, but Trezor Wallet requires Bitcore.

## What I have tried:

### 1. Installing the latest bitcore version according to [the guide](https://bitcore.io/guides/full-node).

This doesn't install [due to a bug](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore/issues/1454), but after working around it I got it running. But unfortunately it then [crashes during indexing](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-node/issues/463), so is unusable.

### 2. Use SatoshiLabs's bitcore fork

SatoshiLabs have made [a fork](https://github.com/satoshilabs/bitcore) of bitcore for use with Trezor Wallet. This looks very promising, especially as it is designed to work with Trezor Wallet, they have fixed the bug in the Bitpay version, and also added better fee estimates. However it also fails to install on OSX, because the embedded Bitcoin Core build [is only packaged for Linux](https://github.com/satoshilabs/bitcoin/releases/tag/v0.15.0).

## Next steps

I can see four options:

1. Go back to trying to get vanilla bitcore working. Find the cause of the crash and fix / workaround.
2. Try to get SatoshiLabs' fork working on OSX. Maybe I can use a vanilla Bitcoin Core build instead of the bundled one? Although I'd probably have to spend a lot of time investigating how to set up the dependencies and run the install correctly.
3. Forget about OSX and set up a simple Linux server and try again.
4. Give up and just let Trezor Wallet use its defaults.

Can I get a working bitcore node on my OSX machine for use with Trezor Wallet? Preferably I'd like to do it without hacking the default config or source code too much.

Comment: A nice article about some merits for being able to validate against our own full node: https://medium.com/@lopp/securing-your-financial-sovereignty-3af6fe834603

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcore fork from SatoshiLabs is indeed available only for 64-bit linux.

You can try to build the necessary binaries yourself and then update the npm install scripts in bitcore, but that is very hard.

I would not recommend you to run bitcore on a personal computer, since it adds additional 200GB data, so you will end up with about half a terabyte of data. Also, because of some performance issues in the bitcore code, the address database synchs for days (around a week), where you cannot use the computer for anything else. (Also the disk SHOULD be SSD, or the syncing is even longer.)

If you want your own backend, I would recommend paying for a Linux server (but it's hard to find a reasonably priced VPS/hosted server with 500GB disk).

All in all, it is not easy to use Trezor with your own full node, unfortunately.

---

I am actually working for SatoshiLabs, on the backends, right now :) and we don't have plans to make the builds on OS X, since we won't be able to test them anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. :-) Not the answer I wanted but I understand.

Comment: Long term, we are planning to move away from bitcore to something simplier, but we are just exploring that right now